# Typescript ClassDecorator target type

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I'm writing my own decorators in typescript. Currently, my decorators look like this:

```
const Controller = (prefix = ''): ClassDecorator => (target: any): void => {
  // My Logic
};

export default Controller;
```

My question is about the ClassDecorator argument. Currently, I'm using the `any` type for the `target` parameter but I need a specific type for this argument. So my question is how is this type named?

I googled for a while but found nothing about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to explicitly state the return type of Controller because the compiler will infer it. as long as you type the arguments of your inner function ..

```
type MyType = { foo: number }

function f() {
  console.log('f(): evaluated')
  return function (target: MyType) {
    console.log('f(): called' + target.foo)
  }
}

``
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is create an interface and have your class implements it.

```
// interface.ts 
export interface ExampleInterface {
    // just some method that is going to get use 
    start(): void 
    stop(): void 
}
```

Then in your decorator

```
import { ExampleInterface } from 'interface'
export function ExampleDecorator(target: ExampleInterface ) {
    // do things with your decorator 
}
```

Now create your class

```
import { ExampleInterface } from 'interface'
import { ExampleDecorator } from 'decorator'

@ExampleDecorator
export class ExampleClass implements ExampleInterface {

   start(): void {
      // do your start thing
   }

   stop(): void {
      // do  your stop thing 
   }

   someOtherMethod() {
      // do some other thing
   }

   set someSetter(value: string) {
      // set some other value 
   }
}
```

I use this on class / method / accessor decorator, all pass the type checking.

---

Another way to make it more generic which is using generic

This example is from a library I created

```
export function Validate<T>(rules?: ValidatorRules) {
  return (target: T, propertyName: string): void => {
    // more code ... 
  }
}
```

The above example is a method decorator that accept a rules.

```
class YourApi {

    @Validate<YourApi>()
    myMethod(name: string, value: number) {
        // do your thing 
    }

}
```